# cygwin rsync all log locations

Tags: windows, cygwin, rsync

I'm trying to secure an rsync file transfers between two machines through cygwin on windows.

Where are the location of all log files that rsync creates? I'm currently using

```
rsync -e ssh -avzP --delete "/cygdrive/C/secure/data/" "/cygdrive/D/data" --log-file=/cygdrive/C/secure/log/c.log
```

When rsync starts it says 'building file list' is this done in memory or is it writing a temp file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You asked if "building file list..." happens in memory, or is stored somewhere. Let's take a look at [rsync's sources](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=summary), namely, `flist.c`:

```
2089         rprintf(FLOG, "building file list\n");
2090         if (show_filelist_p())
2091                 start_filelist_progress("building file list");
2092         else if (inc_recurse && INFO_GTE(FLIST, 1) && !am_server)
2093                 rprintf(FCLIENT, "sending incremental file list\n");
2094 
2095         start_write = stats.total_written;
2096         gettimeofday(&start_tv, NULL);
2097 
2098         if (relative_paths && protocol_version >= 30)
2099                 implied_dirs = 1; /* We send flagged implied dirs */
2100 
2101 #ifdef SUPPORT_HARD_LINKS
2102         if (preserve_hard_links && protocol_version >= 30 && !cur_flist)
2103                 init_hard_links();
2104 #endif
2105 
2106         flist = cur_flist = flist_new(0, "send_file_list");
2107         if (inc_recurse) {
2108                 dir_flist = flist_new(FLIST_TEMP, "send_file_list");
2109                 flags |= FLAG_DIVERT_DIRS;
2110         } else
2111                 dir_flist = cur_flist;
```

`flist_new` just allocates a new file list pool, without doing anything. The string parameter is there to inform about out of memory errors.

Then there are several hundred lines whose purpose is to send the file list. There are no `rprintf` calls whatsoever in there, except for possible error messages. The most interesting function calls in that loop are calls to `send_file_name`, but these don't call `rprintf` too.

So **yes, it builds the files in memory**, and you can't log it without patching the sources yourself. Furthermore, not everything in rsync is logged to log file, some messages are printed directly to your screen. In fact, you might be better off using simple shell redirection, depending on your progress settings. (Or use `tee` to print output to a file and your stdout simultaneously.)